# Wordpress: How to show a link only on a specific page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created my website in WordPress which has four links as follows:

```
HOME | CONTACT | GET FREE QUOTE | ABOUT
```

The `"GET FREE QUOTE"` link only works on my home page because it's pointing to the id of my "get free quote" section of the page

```
<a href="#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>
```

At the bottom of my home page, I have a section with an id of `"quote"` so when I click on `"get free quote"` link I am taken to that section. So it's unnecessary to show it on other pages of my website. I tried searching on google but I didn't find the solution.

my site http://cashforcarsbrizbane.com/

Answer (score 1):

For the other pages you don't provide the entire link destination of the section. In order to fix that link you have to add the url address of the page too, so:

```
<a href="#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>
```

**You should change to:**

```
<a href="http://cashforcarsbrizbane.com/#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>
```

If you use a custom template for the homepage then your code should be:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>
```

To understand better if the quote was in the contact page, for example, the link's destination must have the page where you created the #quote section, and code will be:

```
<a href="http://cashforcarsbrizbane.com/contact/#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/contact' ) ); ?>#quote"> GET FREE QUOTE </a>
```

Comment: yeah it seems right . but can i hide it if i want ?

Comment: From the menu options you can hide a link if you add a custom css class, for example hide-menu-item, but you have to create that class in your style.css file .hide-menu-item{display:none} An easy solution will be to remove it. Also please mark my answer as the good one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should your `"GET FREE QUOTE"` code at the footer section with if condition as:

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;//returns page slug name
$pages_array = array("home","about","conatact");//you can add or remove pages names
if(in_array($post_slug,$pages_array)){

// put get free quote here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using a plugin name [if-menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/). It will help you to select some logic in **Menu Option**. Please check the link. You can find a Option named **Front Page**, you make your menu item visible for **Front Page** only.

Hope this helps.